# Eigen Matrix library coefficient wise manipulation

Tags: c++, eigen

May I please seek help with a computation issue of the matrix library "Eigen."

say i have a functor:

```
    struct my_F
    {
      double a_,b_;
      my_F(double a,double b):a_(a),b_(b){};
      double operator()(double x){return (x+a)*(x+b);}
    }
```

Now I want to use this functor to operate on a Eigen::MatrixXd

```
Eigen::MatrixXd a(10,12);
a.setConstant(2.);
```

How do I write something (in a compact and nice way) so that each element of "a" is taken and the functor operation to it is applied.

I can always do it in a loop but is that the only way out ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look for `unaryExpr` in the doc of Eigen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a `unaryExpr` onto your matrix:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd M(10,12);
//fill matrix M

auto f = my_F{1.0,2.0};
auto M_new = M.unaryExpr(f);
```

Note that the result of the transformation `M_new` is not stored, but evaluated on the fly (as usual in expression template libraries). If you want to store the result, replace "`auto M_new`" by "`Eigen::MatrixXd M_new`".

Comment: thank you very much. that was exactly what i wanted.